# How can I implement a contact form into my Jekyll site, if I need to send a confirmation email to sender too? PHP is available too

Tags: php, html, forms, email, jekyll

I've been looking at formspree.io and simpleform, etc, and while they send an email to me upon sending the contact form, the sender does not recieve an email. I would like to send something like

> Hello, we will be in contact with you as soon as possible.

Now, a php solution is available too, that would be the easiest, but I feel like it would defeat the whole purpose of jekyll, or at least I don't know a good enough solution to implement it while playing nice with Jekyll?
What would you do?

Answer (score 0):

So you want to load a PHP library with a few thousand lines of unknown and possibly vulnerable PHP to make your server capable of sending email to anyone? Just for the sake of 'moving' the message from the screen to the clients inbox? I think that is a bad idea.

If there was a way to do this with an auto-reply I would suggest that, but I think you should try to be happy with the Formspree solution.

Comment: The site is already hosted on a LAMP stack


But yeah, I was trying to look at the auto reply

Answer (score -1):

Once a form is sublitted on http://formspree.io/, you can send your user to a tank you page. See advanced feature on they home page.

An I guess that others forms providers offers such functionality.

Comment: Another alternative is  www.enformed.io, has a couple of interesting features, like setting the redirect after submiting, and email customization.